# How to delete image from database codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

This my controller:

```
public function doDelete($id_jeans)
{
    $where = array("id_jeans" => $id_jeans);
    $res = $this->admin_model->DeleteData('jeans', $where);
}
```

This my model:

```
public function DeleteData($tabelname, $where)
    {
        if ($this->db->delete($tabelname, $where)) {
            redirect("admin/admin/index");
        }else {
            echo "tidak berhasil";
        }
        $res = $this->db->delete($tabelname, $where);
        return $res;            
    }
```

How can I delete an image with CodeIgniter?

Comment: are you storing the image name or path in your db column or are you storing the image in blob format  ??

Answer (score 0):

You are only removing data from a table. If you want to delete a file from a directory:

```
public function DeleteData($tabelname, $where, $path_to_file)
{
    if ($res = $this->db->delete($tabelname, $where)) {
        unlink($path_to_file);
        redirect("admin/admin/index");
    }else {
        echo "tidak berhasil";
    }           
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, I am still puzzled by how to make $path_to_file